# Where can I find IIS in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis

I’ve got IIS installed and enabled on Windows 7, but I don’t know where to open it so that I can configure a website.

I seem to remember that in Windows XP it was somewhere in the Control Panel, but I can’t find it in Windows 7.

Comment: To enable tracing - http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests

Comment: @blasto: I’m not clear how that’s related to the location of IIS’s interface in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah — it’s still in the control panel, I just couldn’t find where.

- Start
- Control Panel
- System and Security
- Administrative tools

(And if you’re viewing by large or small icons instead of by category, you go straight to Administrative Tools.)

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 21):

Before that you have to enable the IIS for windows by

1. start
2. Control panel
3. programs
4. Turn windows feature on / off
5. Check the IIS services (4th and 5th
   checkbox)
6. ok
7. restart the system

Comment: Very true: I had it enabled, but if I didn’t it wouldn’t show up in Administrative Tools.

Comment: Didn't have to restart my Windows 7 machine after enabling it.

Comment: I was somewhat concerned because instead of seeing a check inside the checkbox it just turned blue.  But after restart it was indeed there.

Answer (score 9):

Question is answered I know, but you can always use <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `inetmgr` then press either <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

(I'm a keyboard fan)

Comment: Or type *iis* into the start menu search box thingy.

Answer (score 5):

Only you need to do is go to your control panel.

[image: Control panel]

There in Program->Programs and Features->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features on and off. Click on Windows Features on and off. Click Checkbox Internet Information Services and Click Ok Button.

[image]

Then go to Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools. 
There you will find IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative tools

enable sections of IIS - World Wide Web Services & Web Management Tools

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the IIS using services:

- C:\Windows\system32
- Services
- Open it
- Start the IIS services